# Mailchimp: Editable links in the design view, how to change them?

Tags: html, url, html-email, mailchimp, newsletter

I created a template with editable areas and it just works like a charm,

the thin is that i need to define few different links so they can be changed for each campaign,

I tried:

`<a href="*|CUSTOM_URL1|*">A link</a>`
`<a href="*|CUSTOM_URL2|*">A link</a>`
`<a href="*|CUSTOM_URL3|*">A link</a>`
`<a href="*|CUSTOM_URL4|*">A link</a>`

But then in the preview mode I have no option  to edit this link,

Any idea how to set this custom url values for each campaign?

Comment: MailChimp merge tags are typically used to pull in data from the subscriber's unique list data (i.e. the subscriber's name). can you confirm that this is your intention? that you're defining unique URLs for each subscriber in your list and inserting it through merge tags?

Comment: also, it'd be helpful if you provided your template's code so we can see what areas are editable and where these urls are intended to be placed.

Comment: I want to just let the sender change the links for each campaign, but same ones for all recivers, no segmentation. I will publish the code when I get access to it, asap. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying in the comments.

I don't think you're looking to use merge tags, since you're just trying to change links in the template, not necessarily insert subscriber-specific info. So, the focus should just be making the links in the template editable by the sender, in the MailChimp editor. This way, the sender can create a campaign, select the template and edit the regions/links that you want to be editable.

To make a region editable, use the [MailChimp template language](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/template-language-creating-editable-content-areas/). You can't make "a" tags themselves editable, but you can make a surrounding div or td editable.

```
<td mc:edit="links">
<a href="http://www.google.com">A link</a>
<a href="http://www.mailchimp.com">A link</a>
</td>
```

You may also find the information in this answer helpful.

[MailChimp Editable buttons inline styling is overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651037/mailchimp-editable-buttons-inline-styling-is-overridden)

Answer (score 3):

The tactic above will work well however because the editable region is on the `<td>` it means the user could delete links by accident.

If you want them to be able to edit links, but not mess up your layout you could put the editable region on the link itself as below.

```
<td>
<a href="http://www.google.com" mc:edit="link1">A link</a>
<a href="http://www.mailchimp.com" mc:edit="link2">A link</a>
</td>
```

The reason I would do it this way is to retain the aesthetics i.e. if creating a menu you would not want people to add text or an image by accident, thus making the link the editable region makes only the link part editable.

You need to use link1 link2 etc so they are all unique.

You may also find the information in this answer helpful.

[MailChimp Editable buttons inline styling is overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651037/mailchimp-editable-buttons-inline-styling-is-overridden)

Comment: FWIW this lets you edit the link's text node, not the value of the href attribute; therefore, it may not be the right solution for some.

Comment: Ah I hadn't thought of that.  In which case you would want to create `<td>` for each `<a>` link if you really want to retain layout control.