# MailChimp Editable buttons inline styling is overridden

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

I have created a MailChimp template with Editable Regions.

I've styled everything inline, and I have an editable button as so:

```
              <!-- button -->      
              <table class="button" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Roboto,  'Times New Roman', Times, serif;border-left:1px solid #24303f;border-right:1px solid #24303f;border-bottom:1px solid #24303f;border-top:1px solid #24303f;margin:0 auto;min-width:248px;text-align:center;">
                <tr style="font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
                  <td height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse;font-family: ColdLilies-Regular, Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;"><table class="table-inner" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Roboto, Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
                      <tr style="font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
                        <td align="center" style="font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size:19px;color: #24303f;border-collapse: collapse;padding-left:35px;padding-right:35px;" class="variable-width-button-container">
<a href="#" style="color: #24303f;text-decoration: none;font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size:19px;font-weight:normal;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;" mc:edit="Centred Button" class="variable-button">
View&nbsp;More
</a>
</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table>                  
              <!-- end button -->
```

As you can see I have used `mc:edit="Centred Button"` to make the button editable.  I have also styled the link inline.

When I use the MailChimp interface and edit the button, editing text is fine and retains the style, but as soon as I change the link URL it becomes blue and underlined.

Even switching the editor to source code and inserting inline styles doesn't override the issue.  MailChimp doesn't have a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by MailChimp adding in another `<a href="">` into an editable `<a>`

A possible solution is to use either `a * {styles:here}` or `a a {}`.

A better solution would be to put the `mc:edit` on the preceding `<td>` instead of on the `<a>` to avoid

`<a href="#"><a href="#">Link Text </a></a>`

According to the W3C specification you should not have an `<a>` inside an `<a>`.  In HTML email using valid HTML is a very good idea as the email clients render things oddly at the best of times.

Originally I had put the edit on the `<a>` to retain my layout, but I don't think that is the best option any more.  I used to use the following code:

**CSS**

```
.button a {
    styles
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="button">
        <a>Link Text</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**
MailChimp will inline the style when you send it, and it will work on Gmail etc.

Comment: This was so helpful.  I'm coding a Mailchimp template right now and couldn't figure out for the life of me why my link styles weren't sticking.  Good to know that Mailchimp will apply inline styles when sending!

Comment: Before I wrote this Q/A MailChimp warned me saying I had asked too many low quality questions.  Often I can't find the answer so I post a Q & A.  Glad it helped someone

Comment: If you feel it is the right answer please mark it as so